# How should I issue an alert that times out in swift

Tags: swift, uialertcontroller

I am using a `UIAlertController` to display a user alert that requires a user action. I would like to skip the user action and make the alert disappear after some time (say 10 seconds). What is the best approach to do that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dismiss UIAlertView after 5 Seconds Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27613926/dismiss-uialertview-after-5-seconds-swift)

Comment: The approach is applicable but the solution suggested by Chackle works 'almost' out of the box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this after creating your UIAlertViewController

```
var dispatchTime: dispatch_time_t = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(10.0 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC))) 
dispatch_after(dispatchTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), { 
    yourAlertViewController.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)   
})
```

Comment: @SyedTariq Glad to hear it Syed

Answer (score 1):

This will work perfectly fine for you

```
    //Define & Initialize Alert (Example)
    var alert: UIAlertController = UIAlertController();      

    // Delay the execution (Dismiss AlertController) by 10 seconds
    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 10 * NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        alert.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    });
```